# Can I install a SATA 6 Gb/s SSD on a laptop that came with a SATA 1.5 Gb/s hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata

I am having a ASUS F8Vr laptop. It has a 250GB SATA I HDD. I am planing of changing it to a SSD HDD, may b [Corsair Force Series GS CSSD-F360GBGS-BK](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233313). Not decided yet. Can I do this?

I know the performance of the disk will be reduced as it is SATA III but I will be upgrading the laptop in some time. Till then can SSD replace my current HDD?

[Specs of my current HDD](http://go-ahead.in/books/HDD.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the SATA connectors and communication protocol have remained backwards compatible across versions, there should not be a problem with installing the drive.  See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) for more details.